# Angular typescript switch case by some values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, switch-statement, case

I just try to make a switch by two values.

```
switch ({'a': val_a,'b': val_b}){
  case ({'x','y'}):
    "some code here"
    break;
}
```

and this not working...
any help?
thanks!

Comment: ...what kind of equality comparision should happen in the expression above, in your opinion, i wonder ( aka, `isEqual("{'a': val_a,'b': val_b}", {'x','y'}`)...? :/

Comment: To begin with this is a JSON object, not a JavaScript object. JavaScript objects don't have strings for keys. `{ a: val_a, b: val_b }` is a JavaScript object. `{ 'a': val_a, 'b': val_b }` is a JSON object. You would either need this parsed if it is indeed JSON with `JSON.parse(obj)` or figure out what's going on your side before attempting a switch case.

Answer (score 1):

Switch operator only works for primitives, it's not possible to compare objects, but you can create primitive by yourself, e.g string

```
const compareValue = val_a + ' ' + val_b;

switch (compareValue){
  case 'x y':
    //"some code here"
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value in a **case** statement must be a **constant** or a **literal** or an expression that evaluates to a **constant** or a **literal**. You can't expect a switch statement to have objects and underyling **case** statements have their own objects and do a comparison.

Having said that you've options in javascript that allow you to transform an object (just for comparison purpose). An approach I would following would be like this

```
let obj = {'a': 'x','b': 'y'};
let obj1={a:'x',b:'y'};
switch(Object.values(obj).join(','))
{
 case Object.values(obj1).join(','):
   console.log('evaluation succeeds');
 break;
}
```

So what I've done is took the object values and joined with a comma(effectively having a string), and in the case statement did same with **another object** (so that comparison could take place)

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(true) {
  case obj1.a == obj2.a && obj1.b == obj2.b:
    console.log('true');
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you figure out whether you have a real JavaScript object or if you have to parse a JSON into a object first, your case needs to include the entire object to work.

It would look like this:

```
const obj = { a: "value_a", b: "value_b" };

switch (obj) {
  case { a: "value_a", b: "value_b" }:
    // insert your code here
    break;
  default:
  case { a: "value_a2", b: "value_b3" }:
    // insert your code here
    break;
}
```

As long as your case matches the entire object, it will work fine. Or you could make one to match a single property, which in that case would look like:

```
switch (obj.a) {
  case "value_a":
    // insert your code here
    break;
  default:
  case "value_a2":
    // insert your code here
    break;
}
```